# How to validate output generated by bash script that was executed by Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I have a docker file that that has multiple steps, one of those steps is

```
ENTRYPOINT ./setup.sh
```

Once that I run docker file I'm just seeing the step and if it was executed corrrectly, like this:

```
Step 4/9 : ENTRYPOINT ./setup.sh
```

I just want to see what's the setup.sh script is doing, I added to the script `set -x` but I had no luck

There's a way to see the output of ./setup.sh?

Answer (score 2):

`ENTRYPOINT` is executed at *runtime*, not build time. During the build it's doing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Start a container using the image you built. Then run: docker logs [container id]